# Default equality for record types?

Tags: purescript

I'm doing this exercise from the end of chapter 3 in *The Purescript Book*:

> Write a function which looks up an Entry given a street address, by reusing the existing code in findEntry. Test your function in PSCi.

I tried:

```
findByAddress address = head <<< filter filterEntry
  where
    filterEntry :: Entry -> Boolean
    filterEntry entry = entry.address == address
```

which errors with:

```
  No type class instance was found for

    Data.Eq.Eq { street :: String
               , city :: String  
               , state :: String 
               }                 


while applying a function eq
  of type Eq t0 => t0 -> t0 -> Boolean
  to argument entry.address
while inferring the type of eq (entry.address)
in value declaration findByAddress
```

**Question 1:** I would think record types have a default equality function, namely that all of the record attributes are equal.  Is there one?  How do I use it?

**Question 2:** Just in case my assumption above in Question 1 was false, I tried:

```
eq :: Address -> Address -> Boolean 
eq address1 address2 = address1.street == address2.street &&
                       address1.city == address2.city &&
                       address1.state == address2.state
```

But this did not resolve the problem.  Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bower install purescript-record-extra

pulp repl
> import Data.Record.Extra (eqRecord)

> {a:1, b:2.5} `eqRecord` {a:1, b:2.5}
true

> {a:1, b:2.5} `eqRecord` {a:1, b:3.5}
false

-- different record types cannot be compared

> {a:1, b:2.5} `eqRecord` {a:1, b:3.5, c:"abc"}
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at  line 1, column 25 - line 1, column 45

  Type of expression contains additional label c.

while checking that expression { a: 1    
                               , b: 3.5  
                               , c: "abc"
                               }         
  has type { a :: Int   
           , b :: Number
           }            
while applying a function ((eqRecord (#dict RowToList t2 t1)) (#dict EqRecord t1 t2)) { a: 1  
                                                                                      , b: 2.5
                                                                                      }       
  of type { | t0 } -> Boolean
  to argument { a: 1    
              , b: 3.5  
              , c: "abc"
              }         
in value declaration it

where t0 is an unknown type
```

Update pkg purescript-record has an equality op.

```
> import Data.Record (equal)
> {a:1, b:2.5} `equal` {a:1, b:2.5}
true

> {a:1, b:2.5} `equal` {a:1, b:3.5}
false

> {a:1, b:2.5} `equal` {a:1, b:2.5, c:"abc"}
Error found:
in module $PSCI
at  line 1, column 22 - line 1, column 42

  Type of expression contains additional label c.

while checking that expression { a: 1    
                               , b: 2.5  
                               , c: "abc"
                               }         
  has type { a :: Int   
           , b :: Number
           }
```

Using *newtypes* and *derived instances*:

```
> newtype Address = Address {street::String, city::String}

> derive instance eqAddress :: Eq Address

> Address {street:"la Rambla", city:"Barcelona"} == Address {street:"main", city:"LA"}
false
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.  Can you explain why my attempted fix in Question 2 didn't work?

Comment: @Jonah The sample in Q.2 compiles and works well if you give `eq` a name that does not hide the `Prelude.eq`. But `Data.Record (equal)` or `Data.Record.Extra (eqRecord)` seem a general equality for records

Comment: @Jonah I have added (to the text) derived equality instances in *record* newtypes.